# Варіант перекладу для терміну trie (префіксне дерево)

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Термін *trie* ввели 1960 року, і він є скороченням для "Re*trie*val". Інша назва це prefix tree, у нас - префіксне дерево. Хотілось би знайти переклад власне для *trie*.

По суті, префіксне дерево це структура даних, призначена для швидкого пошуку по словнику. Приклад для слів *лазня, лад, стежка, стерно, страва*:

[image]

Ось переклади слова retrieval від яких я намагався знайти підхоже скорочення:

> по́шук; вибира́ння; відна́йдення, видобува́ння;
>
> верта́ння/вороття́/‌пове́рнення; відно́влювання/відно́влення; виправля́ння/ви́правлення; по́шук (інформації)

але цей напрямок не дав цікавого варіанту. Натомість просте скорочення від **пре**фіксне дере**во**, дало мені **прево**, що співзвучно із древо і коротко, що робить його зручним у використанні.

Наскільки такий словотвір тут доречний? Можливо кращі варіанти?

Comment: Віддієслівні іменники на зразок `вибирання`, `вертання` виглядають невдалими.

Comment: думаю тут гра слів, яку можна спробувати передати як `де-ре-во`

Comment: Префіксне дерево цілком вдало, для скорочення можливо просто дерево, коли з контексту зрозуміло, що мова про термін, або якщо він використовується не вперше в тексті. Уточнення: зрозумів, що ви про вибірку значення з дерева. Ну от вибірку значення, або вибірку можно використовувати. Або термін пошук.

Comment: А чому зупинятися на **прево**, якщо можна взяти власне **ДРЕВО**, тому що **ПРЕ**фіксне де**РЕВО** - тільки замість пре- беремо дре-.

Comment: @Artemix є багато різних дерев і майже кожне з них можна назвати древом, тому неможливо буде відрізнити від інших без контексту, англійське [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) має лише одне значення і це дуже зручно. Займати таке слово як древо для одного терміну якось задорого:)

Comment: @AlexSodin друга назва trie - prefix tree. Тому префіксне дерево це таки добре, але довго, добре мати короткі влучні терміни інакше люди їх просто не використовуватимуть. Про вибірку і пошук не зрозумів.

Comment: @Chizh вибачте, не зрозумів:(

Comment: Retrieval - це основна операція для пошуку та сортування на зібраному індексі, і якщо шукати в такій структурі слово `дерево`, то можна, але не обов'язково, почерзі натикнутися на вершини з ключами: `де`, потім `ре`, потім `во`. Хоча, так, спроба не дуже вдала

Comment: Інші слов'янські мови не морочать голову, і або використовують `trie`, або `префіксне дерево`.

Answer (score 4):

[Історія походження](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#History_and_etymology) *trie*:

> Trie were first described by Rene de la Briandais in 1959.
>   The term trie was coined two years later by Edward Fredkin, who
>   pronounces it `/ˈtriː/` (as "tree"), after the middle syllable of
>   *retrieval*. However, other authors pronounce it `/ˈtraɪ/` (as
>   "try"), in an attempt to distinguish it verbally from "tree".
>
> *Trie* вперше описав Рене де ла Briandais в 1959 році. Термін *trie* був
>   запропонований два роки по тому Едвардом Фредкіном, який вимовляв його
>   як `/ˈтріː/` (від англ. *tree* - *дерево*) - від середнього складу слова
>   re**tri**val. Проте інші автори вимовляти його `/трай/` (від англ.
>   *try* - *спроба* або *спробувати*), щоб при усній вимові можна було
>   його відрізнити від *tree* (*дерево*).

Як видно з цього опису, новий термін не *спростив*, а, навпаки, **ускладнив** роботу авторів, оскільки вимови *trie* та *tree* співпадали і їх потрібно було якось відрізняти.

Тепер розглянемо *теоретичну* можливість створення нових термінів для різних деревовидних структур даних.

Є велика кількість дерев, наприклад:

- бінарне або двійкове дерево (binary tree);
- повне (закінчене) двійкове дерево;
- ідеальне двійкове дерево;
- бінарне або двійкове дерево пошуку (binary search tree, BST);
- червоно-чорне дерево (red-black tree, RB tree);
- збалансоване дерево;

  - B-дерево (B-tree);
- AVL-дерево;
- префіксне дерево (trie або prefix tree);
- суфіксне дерево (suffix tree, PAT tree, position tree);
- та ін.

Якщо використовувати логіку оригінального терміну, то, очевидно, що такий підхід не підійде, оскільки автори терміну обіграли схожіть у вимові *tree* і *trie*, що не переноситься на українську мову.

---

*Чисто теоретично*, якщо використати запропонований вами підхід щодо словотворення на прикладі *префіксне дерево* - *прево*, то *суфіксне дерево* прийдеться назвати *суфво*, *B-дерево* - *B-во*, двійкове дерево пошуку - *двідепош*.